# play images in a loop with interval in react native and cancel the loop on click

Tags: reactjs, react-native

console is printing fine with interval of a second I just dont know how to add images in that loop or create a function that auto play the images in render method. Also i want to cancel the Loop on cancel button.

```
**import React, { Component } from 'react';

  import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
    export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
  images: [require('./images/_1.jpg'),
  require('./images/_2.jpg'),
  require('./images/_3.jpg')],
   };
  }
    componentDidMount() {
   var intervalId = setInterval(function () {

     var timoutId = setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("wait for me!");
  }, 1000);

}, 1000);

  }
  render() {

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>



    <Image style={{ width: 400, height: 400 }}
      source={this.state.images[2]}
    />
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.button}
      onPress={console.log("Cancel Loop")} //do not know how to create cancel function
    >
      <Text> Cancel Loop </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
    );
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to increase the index counter for the images in your state array

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import img1 from './images/_1.jpg'
import img2 from './images/_2.jpg'
import img3 from './images/_3.jpg'

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      images: [img1, img2, img3],
      index: 0,
    };
    this.timoutId = null
    this.intervalId = null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({ index: prevState.index + 1 }))
    }, 1000)
  }

  nextImgHandler = () => {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId)
    this.setState(prevState => ({ index: prevState.index + 1 }))
  }

  prevImgHandler = () => {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId)
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      if (prevState.index === 0) {
        return { index: 2 }
      } else {
        return { index: prevState.index - 1 }
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { index } = this.state
    const img = this.state.images[index % 3]
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={{ width: 400, height: 400 }}
          source={img}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => clearInterval(this.intervalId)}
        >
          <Text> Cancel Loop </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => this.nextImgHandler()}
        >
          <Text> Next </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => this.nextImgHandler()}
        >
          <Text> Prev </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: that %3 is as if you see in setInterval you are increasing the index for after 3rd time your index will be 4 then 5 and so on and images are only 3 so when you do %3 what you are doing is at 4 it will access 4 % 3 = 1, 5 % 3 = 2 then 6 % 3 = 0 and so on

Comment: how can i add another button which will not only stop the interval (clearInterval) but also move to the next image and a previous button which will also move to previous index

Comment: I have updated the answer you just need to increase the index one more time, thats all, and for prevImg you can just decrease the index once after clearing the interval

Comment: Thank You @warl0ck for Your Help. This Is Great Work.

Comment: consider upvoting as well if it helped :)

Comment: previousImgHandler = () => {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    this.setState(prevState => ({ index: prevState.index - 1 }))

  } its not working for showing previous index image if index is 0.....

Comment: you can just put a check while doing -1 if index is already 0 mean you want it to point to last one i.e. index 2 so instead of `prevState.index - 1` do `index: 2`

Comment: Not Working Bro if for the last time u could rewrite the code with previous image handler Please :).......